# A310 wing attachment point details?

Tags: airbus-a310

Does anyone have an SRM (structural repair manual) or AMM (aircraft maintenance manual) available for the Airbus A310?

How is the wing attached to the fuselage?

What types of bolts are used?  Are they any special type (high-strength/titanium/etc.)?

Where can I find details on the A310's wing attachment points?

Comment: Please let us know who's planes you are repairing so we can avoid that airline.

Comment: Its not for repairing purpose , I need it for education purpose. Probably if  working in airline that have a310 in the fleet then I'm pretty sure they would have AMM and SRM Available for staff to study .

Comment: Well add that information into the question. "I need to know ..." sounds like you have just taken the wing off and let the original bolts roll across the floor and get lost.

Comment: Haha, I would accept the  fact that the question I asked is poorly written